# Execute Javascript if Django template variable exist

Tags: javascript, python, django

In my template, I am iterating over a django variable using a `for loop`.

There is a **Carousel** within the td.

What I want to do is add an overlay over the **td with class CAROUSEL** and **not** to anything within the If condition. if `animal.available` exist. Maybe execute javascript and add class that would add an overlay over the **td**. Basically, There should be a difference between the carousels where `animal.available` and where it doesn't.

> Basically, when inner html tag is populated by Django variable, I want the parent html to be overlayed.

### template.html

```
<table>
    <td class="carousel">
    {% for animal in stores %}
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Name: {{ animal.name }} </li>
                <li>Price: {{ animal.price }}</li>
            </ul>
        {% if animal.available %}
            <!-- Add overlay over td ->
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
</table>
```

### Overlay css

```
.overlay {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

How do I add overlay class to td with class carousel if django variable **animal.available** exist? There are many such td's in the table, generated dynamically, so adding ID to the elements is also not possible.

Comment: What's your question? You don't know how to add overlay? If so, it does't seem to have anything to do with django but it's a css/javascript question.

Comment: You could just add an html with proper css, you shouldn't even need js here.

Comment: @ShangWang: I want to add an overlay to the td with class="carousel" **IF animal.available exist**

Comment: @MauroRocco: See edited question. Basically, when inner html tag is populated by Django variable, I want the parent html to be overlayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a **dummy hidden div** with class `exist` if the django variable `animal.available` **existed** and then added an overlay on the parent TD with class carousel as below.

```
<table>
    <td class="carousel">
    {% for animal in stores %}
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Name: {{ animal.name }} </li>
                <li>Price: {{ animal.price }}</li>
            </ul>
        {% if animal.available %}
            <div class="exist" style="display:none"></div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
</table>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('.exist');
    x.parents('.carousel').addClass('overlay');
});
```

Comment: I'm more inclined to use css than js if possible, and maybe for that reason I offer that you could do what you like with just the template and css.  You could check for animal in animal.stores above your <td class="carousel", and add overlay to that class if the test is met.  All the same, you have obviously solved the issue

Comment: It is in a `for loop` which means animal.stores is a collection of objects in which one of the object may have the `available` field.
How can I check if the field exist outside the loop?
Maybe there is a confusion because of the naming, let me change that.

Comment: Thanks Joel. It was my mistake, should have paid attention to the naming.

Answer (score 1):

No javascript needed. Just close your carousel td, start a new one, put your content in the new td.

```
<table>
<td class="carousel">
{% for animal in animal.stores %}
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: {{ animal.name }} </li>
            <li>Price: {{ animal.price }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% if animal.available %}
        </td><td> add your stuff here
    {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: the if condition did not have any td, by overlay on td, I meant over the **td with class="carousel"**